# How to print an index 0 of a list, with for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Why does this code, does not return (or print) the 0 index of the list?

```
N = int(input())

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

for i in range(N):

    print(letters[i]*i)
```

output: should be:

```
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
EEEEE
FFFFFF
GGGGGGG
```

But im getting this, without the "A":

```
B
CC
DDD
EEEE
FFFFF
GGGGGG
```

Comment: What is `i` in the first iteration? What do you get when anything is multiplied by that `i`?

Comment: Right, I got confused thinking I would get the index 0, which is "A". Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because i starts counting at zero.

If you type:

```
for i in range(10):
print(i)
```

You'll see:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

If you want to count from 1 to N instead of 0 to N-1, type:

```
print(letters[i]*(i+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because 0 times a list wont print it. You need to add 1.

```
N = int(input())

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

for i in range(N):
    print(letters[i]*(i+1))
```

Comment: Slight nitpick: `letters[i]` isn't a list.

Comment: Actually, 0 times a list is an _empty list_ that is still printed as `[]`. Zero times a _string_ is an empty string which doesn't show anything when printed

Answer (score 2):

the `for i in range` starts at 0. It then tries to execute

```py
print(letters[i]*i)
```

At index 0, this translates to

```py
print(letters[0]*0)
```

Since the resulting string is multiplied by zero, it outputs nothing. Changing `i` to `i + 1` would solve this issue, as other commenters have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

the i starts from 0.
So you need:

```
for i in range(N):
    print(letters[i]*(i+1))
```